# GetModuleFileName returns path in 8.3 format

Tags: c++, winapi

I call this function to get path to exe. GetModuleFileName(NULL, ...
The problem is that sometimes it returns the short path (8.3) instead of a normal long path.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies that

```
The string returned will use the same format that was specified when the module was loaded. Therefore, the path can be a long or short file name, and can use the prefix "\\?\".
```

How can I avoid this behavior and force Api to return full path ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot avoid it - if the dll is loaded with a short name, that's what you get.

Use [GetLongPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364980%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to convert if needed.

Comment: +1, Better than `GetFullPathName` (MSDN warns not to use that in multi-threaded programs)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. Use [GetFullPathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the full path.

See also the  Remarks section in the page you linked to:

> The global variable _pgmptr is automatically initialized to the full path of the executable file, and can be used to retrieve the full path name of an executable file.